# How to do translate animation of button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to move a button from one site to another. I manage to move it but when it moves, I have to click on the place where it was before instead of hitting the button. Why does this happen?

[This is how it looks](https://gyazo.com/0e68ab3d31f1e41c9ae3fd886246f58a). You can see how at the end when I click on another side, the button's shadow is activated

My code:

Animation xaml

move.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-300"
        android:toYDelta="-300"
        android:duration="500"
        ></translate>

</set>
```

In the code:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.move);
    btnNext.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the animation is performed by changing the [translationX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:translationX) and translationY view properties, not the actual position which the ui framework authors, in their infinitesimal wisdom, have placed in an external class, inheriting [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams). Consequently the click events are dispatched to the "raw" position of the view which does not account for the view transformations ([reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#property-vs-view)).
Animations in android are still pretty tedious and untamed but at least there are many approaches to take. For this case a ValueAnimator for the LayoutParams fields seems like a solution.
If the layout allows margins then it can look like this:

```
final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) btnNext.getLayoutParams();
int initialX = displayWidth - btnNextWidth, finalX = displayWidth / 2;

ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialX, finalX)
    .setDuration(500)
    .addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
             Integer ax = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
             Log.i("anim", "x: " + ax);
             lp.leftMargin = ax;
             btnNext.requestLayout();
         }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it and in                     Integer ax = (Integer) valAnim.getValue(); , it says,   cannot resolve method 'getValue()'. I tried with getValues() but nothing happen

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the method is called getAnimatedValue; i edited the answer

Comment: valAnim is the valueAnimator parameter of the onAnimationUpdate method in the AnimatorUpdateListener; I edited the answer replacing the java 8 syntax that used a lambda with the inner class syntax which should work on all projects.